# Protractor doesn't work with my button which has a different character

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to get a button element which has the text " Salvar & Fechar", but using

`element(by.buttonText('Salvar & Fechar');`

protractor just can't find the element. Why?

I can't use `element(by.partialButtonText('Salvar')` because there is other element with this text and protractor always selecte the first one.

Comment: Do you have any success with `element(by.partialButtonText('Salvar & Fechar'))`?

Comment: I wonder if it's having problems with `& amp;` encoding.

Comment: It's give me 
 `W/element - more than one element found for locator by.partialButtonText("Salvar & Fechar") - the first result will be used`

But I have one button with "Salvar & Fechar"  text and one with "Salvar" 
text

Comment: To get a unique element, add a parent container: `element(by.css(...)).element(by.partialButtonText('Salvar & Fechar'))`

Comment: Can you post the html around the element?

Comment: so you could do element.all(by.partialButtonText('Salvar')).last() [not sure my parentheses are perfect here], but that is a workaround which ducks the question.

Comment: Maybe by.buttonText("Salvar %26 Fechar") will work

Comment: If there is no plain 'Fechar' button, by.partialButtonText('Fechar') should work. If the %26 , .last() or .get(1) on .all fail, one more idea based on http://engineering.wingify.com/posts/angularapp-e2e-testing-with-protractor/ is:  element.all(by.partialButtonText("Salvar")).filter(function(elem) {
     return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
         //Match the label
         return (text.search('Fechar') > -1);
     });
 }).then(function(filteredElements) { //do your stuff to filteredElements[0] (or .get(0) ) in here //there should be only one element in filteredElements
 });

Answer (score 1):

i guess the problem is that the text present on the button need to be trimmed because it has an extra whitespace at the beginning.try the below xpath and check whether it works,

> element(by.xpath(".//button[normalize-space(text())='Salvar & Fechar']"))